# How to fix 'index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0'?

Tags: python

I'm practicing Python. 
Running the code below will cause an error.
I don't know why.

```
    def plot_conv_south_2(sf, title, south, color):
        df = read_shapefile(sf)
        CTP_KOR_ID = []
        for i in south:
            i = conv_south(i).upper()
            CTP_KOR_ID.append(df[df.CTP_KOR_NM == i.upper()]
                             .index.get_values()[0])
        plot_map_fill_multiples_ids(title, CTP_KOR_ID, sf, 
                                           x_lim = None, 
                                           y_lim = None, 
                                           figsize = (11,9), 
                                           color = color);

AA = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']

plot_conv_south_2(sf, 'South', AA, 'c')


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-c2d1c4f0d535> in <module>
----> 1 plot_conv_south_2(sf, 'South', AA, 'c')

<ipython-input-102-27a5c1d3a5cb> in plot_conv_south_2(sf, title, south, color)
      8         i = conv_south(i).upper()
      9         CTP_KOR_ID.append(df[df.CTP_KOR_NM == i.upper()]
---> 10                          .index.get_values()[0])
     11     i = np.array(i)
     12     plot_map_fill_multiples_ids(title, CTP_KOR_ID, sf,
```

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: `.get_values()` is returning an empty list (has size 0). So attempts to access the first element with `[0]` are invalid (the index 0 is out of bounds since there are no elements).

Comment: i'm sorry, can you fix my code???

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's up to you. What I can tell you is that either (a) `.get.value()` should not return an empty list and should be fixed, or (b) it may return an empty list and the code you show should get the return value and check for an empty list before attempting to index it. There's not enough information here for me to tell you which case it is.